# Call C# DLL function from python

Tags: python, c#, dll

I try to call a C# DLL from python.
Note that i have no access to the DLL and the DLL take as arguments and the struncture of the function is as follow :

```
EnregistrementTableauTestsMesures(input as String, input as String, input as String, input as String, input as Array, Output as Boolean, Output as String)
```

```
import numpy as np
import clr
import os
pathDLL = os.getcwd() +'//data//SCProduction.dll'
pathConfig = os.getcwd() + '//data//SCProduction.ini'
clr.AddReference(pathDLL)
from SCProduction import GestionProductions
traca = GestionProductions()
traca.InitialisationParametresGestMES(pathConfig, False, '')
list_ = [['', '', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
arr = np.array(list_)
OF = traca.RecuperationInformationSFC("459212720323", "", "", "", True, "")[1]
print("The OF is ", OF)
retour = traca.EnregistrementTableauTestsMesures("459220831899", "TEST_INSITU", "HP12_TEST-INSITU_01_01", OF, arr, True, "")[6]
print(retour)
```

But when I run the Python code it returns:

```
The OF is  C253727019_G_NRJ_13092021
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/g558426/Desktop/PYTHON/Project_3_Traca with Python_V0/SAP_v2.py", line 21, in <module>
    retour = traca.EnregistrementTableauTestsMesures("459220831899", "TEST_INSITU", "HP12_TEST-INSITU_01_01", OF, arr, True, "")[6]
TypeError: No method matches given arguments for EnregistrementTableauTestsMesures: (<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'bool'>, <class 'str'>)
```

The same DLL I call it from VB.Net and it works.

Here is my code VB

```
 Dim tabMes(,) As String = 
{"test", "test", "10", "test", "", "", "test", "", "TEST OK", "test"}, {"test", "test", "10", "test", "", "", "test", "", "TEST OK", "test"}, {"test", "test", "10", "test", "", "", "test", "", "TEST OK", "test"}} 
 ID_traca.EnregistrementTableauTestsMesures(SFC, Operation, Ressource, OrdreFab, tabMes, RetourTraca, MsgTraca)
```

Please do you have any ideas?

Thank you very much

Comment: Read the error. My python skill havent been used in 2 decades but i can clearly see the error tell you that your the datatypes are wrong and it doesn't find the method in the C# DLL that match those types

Comment: @Franck i'm a beginner in python and i don't know how can i create the tab declared in vb code with python ?

Comment: I want to pass an argument of (,) as String type from python to C# dll function, this is why datatype is wrong.
Please have you any ideas